# Interval for session expiry for AWS SDK, and return code

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-sdk

I am creating a session with AWS this way

```
cfg := aws.NewConfig().WithCredentials(credentials.NewStaticCredentials(accessKeyID, secretAccessKey, "")).WithRegion(region)
sess := session.Must(session.NewSession(cfg))
s3.New(sess)
```

How can I check if the AWS session I created from go-sdk has expired or not.
Is there any fixed time for session expiry or what happens when I use the expired session to make a request to AWS via sdk.
Is there any specific return code or error that I should look for?
I have gone through a similar thread [Does AWS SDK handles session expiry automatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66167568/does-aws-sdk-handles-session-expiry-automatically)

But this doesn't have the solution I need.

My use case is that I create a session at the beginning and use it at 24 hours interval, So I want to make sure that I can find out that the session has expired and I can recreate the session and continue with my task.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no real answer to this because AWS documentation is not clear about session expiry, it only mentions the credentials expiry and interval to refresh them. It would be a good practice to recreate a session whenever a failure happens while using the session.